# Client's site is in Quirks mode in IE8 but it defaults to standard mode for me

Tags: internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

The site renders fine for me in IE8 in Standards mode using a strict doctype. They have IE8 as well and I think it's rendering in Quirks mode for them.

Why would it render in Quirks mode for them and not anyone else? Could it be their Compatibility View Settings? I gave them instructions to uncheck `"Display Intranet sites in Compatibility Mode”` and `“Display all websites in Compatibility Mode”`.

If this doesn't work is there any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IE defaults to Quirks mode when rendering a site on a local network, but standards when from localhost. Try adding a meta tag at the top of your head tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you "think it's rendering in quirks mode"-- why do you think that? If you hit F12 on the page, what do you see in the Developer Tools toolbar for the Document Mode?

"Display Intranet sites in Compatibility Mode" will show Standards Mode sites in IE7 Standards Mode (rather than IE8 or IE9 Standards), and Quirks mode sites will continue to render in Quirks mode.